# Theorem 4.15. of Titchmarsh's Book of the Zeta Function

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, estimation

I have two questions regarding the proof of [Theorem 4.15.](https://imgur.com/a/4o3j4Xh) of Titchmarsh's book The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function:

Question 1: Integral on the counter $C$ in the line 7th of the picture [The first green-underlined] is equal to the sum of integral on the new counter (which is the four straight lines) plus $2 \pi i$ times residues of $\dfrac{w^{s-1}e^{-mw}}{e^w-1}$. Considering that the domain between the two counters consists of simple poles at $\pm 2 \pi i n$, $n=1, 2, \dots, q$, so I got for the second term of RHS of $\zeta(s)$ in the line 16th [The second green-underlined]: $$\bigg( \sum_{n=1}^q (2 \pi i n)^{s-1} + \sum_{n=1}^q (-2 \pi i n)^{s-1} \bigg) e^{- \pi i s} \Gamma(1-s) = \dfrac{1}{2} e^{- \pi i s} \chi(s) \sum_{n=1}^q \dfrac{1}{n^{1-s}},$$ where $\chi(s)=2^s {\pi}^{s-1} \sin \frac12 \pi s \Gamma(1-s).$ I did calculations twice and why am I getting a different result?

Question 2: In the first orange-underlined equation the term ${\eta}^{\sigma -1} e^{\frac{\lambda t}{\eta \sqrt{2}}}$ appears and in the second orange-underlined equation it disappears. How  $\dfrac{e^{-mw}}{e^w-1} = O(e^{\frac{-\lambda t}{\eta \sqrt{2}}})$ makes that term to vanish? Firstly, sum of two $O$ terms may not cancel even if they are negative of each other; secondly, the first one has ${\eta}^{\sigma -1}$ as coefficient but the second one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1, notice that

\begin{aligned}
(2\pi i)^{s-1}+(2\pi i^{-1})^{s-1}
&=(2\pi)^{s-1}(i^{s-1}+i^{1-s})=(2\pi)^{s-1}(i^s-i^{-s})i^{-1} \\
&=2^s\pi^{s-1}{e^{\pi is/2}-e^{-\pi is/2}\over2i}=2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin\left(\pi s\over2\right).
\end{aligned}

For question 2, the O-terms are multiplied instead of added. In general, when $f$ and $g$ are real functions, it is always true that $O(e^f)\cdot O(e^g)=O(e^{f+g})$.

Comment: For Q1, extra e^{- \pi i s} does not go away as you wrote but in the text (see the picture) it does.  Q2 is solved by your answer, thanks!

Comment: For that, my recommendation is to write $e^{-\pi is}u^{s-1}\mathrm du=(-u)^su^{-1}\mathrm du$ before computing the residues, where $(-u)^s$ uses the principal branch.

Comment: If not I am mistaken, the result is the same thing. Could you please write your calculations if you believe that works?

Comment: You are doing the same mistake as the one who is asking the question. What is the contour considered? What are the residues? To avoid this kind of mistakes I'd personally would change your notation which IMO is producing such kind of mistakes.